# Show alternate logo on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to show a high-resolution version of the site's logo on mobile, at the same dimensions as the original.  I tried creating an alternative div with the substitute logo and used `#mobile-logo {display:none}` on desktop and tested both `#mobile-logo{display:block}` and `#mobile-logo{display:inline}` on mobile, but neither worked.

```css
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
#forum-link {
 display:none;
}
#logo{
 display:none;
}
#mobile-logo {
    display:inline;
}
.wide-img{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
}

header {
background-image:url('/img/bg.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
height:116px;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
}

#logo {
margin-left:15px;
}

#mobile-logo{
display:none;
}

#forum-link {
margin-right:35px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div id="logo"><a href="/" title="Home"><img src="/img/logo.png" width="354" height="85"></a></div>
<div id="mobile-logo"><a href="/" title="Home"><img src="/img/logo2x.png" width="354" height="85"></a></div>
<div id="forum-link"><a href="/forum">Forum</a></div>
</header>
```

Could the problem be that the parent div is display:flex?

Comment: Is the logo the `<img />` element or in the header `background-image`? If it's the `<img />` then you need to use `srcset` (not CSS). For CSS use `@media ( min-device-pixel-ratio: $dpi )`.

Comment: Also, don't forget that desktop and laptop users can also have high-DPI screens, not just mobile users.

Comment: What didn't work? The mobile logo didn't show or did it show but was not in high-resolution?

Comment: There is no way to distinguish mobile from desktop in just CSS. A desktop device can have a small window and an HD-DPI display. A mobile device can have a very large screen. Both can have touch screens. [Lots of people run desktops in portrait mode](https://www.google.com/search?q=portrait+mode+desktop&safe=active&tbm=isch) and lots of people use mobile devices in landscape mode.

Comment: @Dai the issue is not that mobile visitors have high DPI screens and desktop visitors don't.  Of course we all have high-resolution monitors.  But in the desktop layout, the logo is only of the divs sharing horizontal space in the header area, and the maximum page width is less than 800px, whereas in mobile view the logo blows up to serve as a header for the entire width of the viewport.  So a 1x logo is totally fine on desktop but loses crispness on mobile.

Comment: @gman As far as people who use their desktop monitors in portrait mode, I don't know what to do about them.  They can use the site with the mobile layout, I guess.  Same goes for mobile users who attempt to view the site in landscape--they get the desktop version.  I turned the phone sideways, and the site looks fine.  I can't design for everyone, and guessing if the user is on mobile based on his resolution is both unreliable and a bit insane.  I just want to design for most users and avoid a Google penalty for lacking mobile-friendly design.

Answer (score 1):

Mobiles aren't the only devices that might have high-resolution screens. Having a high-resolution image and displaying it on devices that support it is a great idea. Fortunately there's a very simple way to approach it rather than rolling your own solution.

### The srcset attribute

Using `srcset`, you can tell the browser to load a different image based on a given width / pixel density. All you need to do is pass it you 1x and 2x logo and it'll handle loading the appropriate image for you.

Example:

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="/" title="Home">
        <img 
          src="/img/logo.png" 
          srcset="/img/logo.png 1x, /img/logo2x.png 2x"
          width="354" 
          height="85" />
    </a>
</div>
```

A common convention you'll see used is labelling your 2x images as @2x (logo@2x.png).

Comment: [There are devices with 1.3x 1.5x 2x 2.5x 2.6x 3x 4x etc...](https://material.io/resources/devices/)

Comment: Yes, just pointing out the common misconception that there are only 2. Also kind of implying that if you want perfection you're going to need to supply a ton of resolutions and keep adding more as new devices come out.

Comment: @gman it's a valid point and you're absolutely right. I remember when the iPhone 6 Plus came out and we were debating whether we'd have to begin creating 3x assets. Thank goodness for SVGs :D

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment, desktop users obviously have high-res monitors too, but this site's layout in desktop mode is limited in width, and so is the space occupied by the logo.  So the low-res logo looks good on the desktop and I don't want to load a high-res logo where it's not needed.